# How Java API work

Tags: java, android, api

How does the API actually  work! I Googled a lot, but the answers are confusing. I know that it is a interface.

For example in Android, if I extend Activity in my code, I could use the API docs to assist me. And what creates the Activity object, i never call new Activity();

What exactly does a API communicate with to achieve the desired results? Is API a class definition?

Comment: For the last question: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface

Comment: See FAQ you will probably not get an exact answer on StackOverFlow, try other StackExchange sites.

Comment: I don't think there is a SE site which could answer this. I really suggest SwiftParser to go deep in Jon's link.

Comment: ["Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much."](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **API is a collection of Classes and Interfaces grouped together mainly according to their functionality.**
2. They are the classes which have the functionality written in them to do things like sorting, making various network connections like Http, ftp connections, File handling .etc..
3. Example:

   java.net will have classes for networking

   java.io for various input-output functionality
4. When using an API class or interface, you either need to write the whole path or use import statement..

**Full path:**

```
java.util.ArrayList<String>  arr = new java.util.ArrayList<String>();
```

**Import**

import java.util.ArrayList ;

```
ArrayList<String>  arr = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Answer (score 0):

API is Application Programming Interface, meaning it is a contract with the class the implements the API that the declared methods are implemented and working.
It can also be referred as 'tag' or 'mask' because some entity representing a dog structure can have API of 'Animal' and 'Washable' while also a car structure can be 'Washable'.

Answer (score 0):

Your activity is created by android whenever it is necessary.   Usually as result of an incoming intent.    Read android docs about activity lifecycle for detailed explanations

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's best to start with the basis of Java, not Android for now. Android is just a platform that uses Java, try playing around with a "void main class" following any java tutorial.

Activity is a class that is instantiated automatically by the platform after having properly configured the AndroidManifest.xml file and with a well defined lifecycle. When you feel ready and Java API's are no longer a mistery for you, then you visit the website: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html and get start Android by writing some awesome stuff!

Good luck!